# Redundant I know, but sIFR in IE 6/7 issue

Tags: internet-explorer-6, internet-explorer-7, sifr

I promise, I've read through hundreds of Joyent posts and stackoverflow questions and I'll preface this by saying I'm certain I have no misplaced commas and have flash installed and have had others try the page in IE.

The issue is that nothing renders in IE 6/7, but IE8, FF, and Safari are all fine.  Here's the code:

```
//sIFR-config.js

var zapfino = { src: '/fonts/zapfino.swf' };

sIFR.fitExactly = true;
sIFR.useStyleCheck = true;
sIFR.useDomLoaded = true;

sIFR.activate(zapfino);

sIFR.replace(zapfino, {
  selector: 'h1, h2, h3, h4'
  ,css: '.sIFR-root { color: #1A2F35; }'
  ,forceSingleLine: true
  ,tuneWidth: 5
  ,wmode: 'transparent'
  ,filters: {
      DropShadow: {
        knockout: false
        ,distance: 3
        ,color: '#330000'
        ,strength: 1
        ,alpha: .45
      }
    }
  ,ratios: [7, 3.59, 9, 3.56, 10, 3.49, 12, 3.5, 13, 3.46, 20, 3.47, 23, 3.43, 26, 3.44, 34, 3.42, 40, 3.41, 42, 3.4, 45, 3.41, 47, 3.4, 49, 3.41, 69, 3.4, 71, 3.39, 72, 3.4, 76, 3.39, 77, 3.4, 3.39]  
});

/* sIFR.css */
@media screen {
    .sIFR-active h1, .sIFR-active h2, .sIFR-active h3, .sIFR-active h4 {
        visibility: hidden;
        font-family: Verdana;
        line-height: 1em;
        color: #ff0000;
    }
    .sIFR-dummy { 
        width: 0px;
        height: 0px;
        margin-left: 42px !important;
        z-index: 0;
    }    
}

<!-- HTML Snippet -->
<div id="header">
    <H1>H1 Example</H1>
    <h3>H3 Example</h3>
    <h2>H2 Example</h2>
    <h4>H4 Example</h4>
</div>
```

Note that nearly every option you see I've tried with and without, cache clearing, etc. Also, the main css absolutely positions h1-4 within div#header, which I've also tried commenting out.

EDIT: Note that the .sIFR-active class is applied to `<html>`, so I know the script is firing, but other than that nothing on the page is altered.

I've also tried different fonts from different sources, still no luck in IE.

TIA,

Jay

Comment: Could you post a link to a live demo page? I assume other sIFR sites do work normally?

Comment: Hey Mark,

Here ya go:  http://hlc-dev.heroku.com/

I haven't used sIFR for previous sites, but would like to add to some production sites when I feel I have a good handle on usage and troubleshooting.

Thanks.

Comment: Oh, you're referring to other sites besides my own - yes I've tried several from your example page without issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes in IE6/7, when an absolute is positioned next to a float, the absolute will disappear.

In your css you have `.1header` floated left and immediately following `.header_text` is positioned absolute.

Try setting `.header_text` to position:relative. Or put an empty div between `.1header` and `.header_text`. Or wrap the div `.header_text` in another div.

*BTW - CSS class names must start with an underscore (_), a dash (-), or a letter(a-z). Starting a class name with a digit is invalid but I don't know if it makes a difference to IE in this case or not.*

*Added after comments*

I am pretty sure that it is a css issue.  Remove the `<h1>...<h4>` with the sifr in #header_text.  Add `<h1>test</h1>`. In the CSS, add 'background-color:#00c;' on #header_text.

Look at it in firefox. You should see a red test on a blue background. Look in IE, you won't.

On #header_text change position:absolute to position:relative. Look in IE, the red test with blue background should show up (not where you want it but that's another issue).

Comment: Thanks, Emily. I tried relatively positioning those and even removing all styling for headings altogether, but thanks for the response.  The .lheader class is actually 'l' not 1, you're absolutely right though - never use a digit as the first char in a class name.

Comment: .header_text was also recently added after I submitted this question.  I needed to stabilize the absolute positioned h1-4.

Comment: I still think it is a css issue and not a sifr issue...see my additional comments above.

Comment: Excellent Emily! In fact, all that needed to be done is changing #header_text to relative. Wow, I've never had IE fail that hard and unpredictably simply due to css - but I also generally avoid that much absolute positioning.  Looks like I need to rethink that whole header, which should be fun because this client is an absolute perfectionist. ;)
Thanks again!